# extending a controller and model that are already extended

Tags: magento-1, extensions, magento-enterprise, controllers, model

Below is my attempt to overwrite two pieces of magento core / enterprise code.  However, I'm unsure as to how to overwrite these because they're already extensions of other pieces of code.  Any elucidation is appreiciated.

Controller class definition:

```
require_once 'Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php';
class Enterprise_Wishlist_IndexController extends Mage_Wishlist_IndexController
```

Model class definition:

```
class Mage_Wishlist_Model_Wishlist extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
```

Attempted controller overwrite definition:

```
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Enterprise_Wishlist') . DS . 'IndexController.php');
class  Namespace_Wishlist_IndexController extends Enterprise_Wishlist_IndexController
```

Attempted Model overwrite definition:

```
class Namespace_Wishlist_Model_Wishlist extends Mage_Wishlist_Model_Wishlist
```

config.xml for module:

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Wishlist>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Namespace_Wishlist>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <wishlist>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Namespace_Wishlist before="Enterprise_Wishlist">Namespace_Wishlist</Namespace_Wishlist>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </wishlist>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <models>
            <wishlist>
                <rewrite>
                    <wishlist>Namespace_Wishlist_Model_Wishlist</wishlist>
                </rewrite>
            </wishlist>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

This is the .xml declaration:

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <namespace_wishlist>
            <active>true</active>
            <codepool>local</codepool>
        </namespace_wishlist>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing it right. There is only one think missing. You need to tell magento that your module depends on `Enterprise_Wishlist` so it will be loaded after that.  Also `codepool` should be `codePool`.
So your declaration xml should look like this:

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Wishlist>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Enterprise_Wishlist />
            </depends>
        </Namespace_Wishlist>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: I could kiss you.

Comment: please don't. You don't know where I've been. :)